# If Parameter A = (Select All) then Default Parameter B to "Y"

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report i have been asked to write from a procedure i did not create the procedure has 2 parameters for each of the options.

```
@AreaID 
@AreaID_All
```

So They coded this way if you wanted to search for a specific Area id you would input the Area ID into **@AreaID** and then input "N" Into **@AreaID_All**.

If you wanted to show all then you would input NULL into **@AreaID** and **"Y"** into **@AreaID_All**.

It was also requested that there be a multiselect dropdown for the **@AreaID**.

I have this part down, now im stuck on how to say if the User Selected **(Select All)** in **@AreaID** then Default the **@AreaID_all** to **"Y"**.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another dataset that returns the count of `AreaID` rows you are passing as available values to the parameter.

Then use it to compare against the `Parameters!AreaID.Count` function.

`@AreaID_All` set expression would be something like this:

```
=Switch(
...
...
First(Fields!CountofAreaID.Value,"CountDataSet")=Parameters!AreaID.Count,"Y"
)
```

This means `Select All` option was select.

Also I strongly suggest you have an internal parameter to validate the data your @AreaID_All is getting from the user.

Let me know if this helps.